# My Jframe won't show up. the code has no errors

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I have no clue whats going on :( we have an assignment to design a pet game, like a tamadotchi game. my pet was a tiger. simple enough idea. but.. apparently eclipse has other plans :(

`enter code here`

```
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.GridLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.Timer;

    import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
    import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
    import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
    import javax.swing.JTextArea;

    public class inter {

private JFrame tigerWindow;
private JPanel topPanel, leftPanel, rightPanel, bottomPanel, middlePanel, allPanels;
private JLabel tigerLabel, happyLabel, hungryLabel, energyLabel, hygieneLabel, picLabel;
private JButton play, sleep, feed, hunt, swim, walk, shop, home;
private JProgressBar happyBar, hungryBar, energyBar, hygieneBar;
private JTextArea tigerText;
private JProgressBar happy, hungry, energy, hygiene;
private int interval;
private Timer timer;

private int tigerHungerCount = 5;
private int tigerHygieneCount = 5; 
private int tigerHappyCount = 5;
private int tigerEnergyCount = 5;


        Pet tiger = new Pet ("Meat", "Roll", "Roar", "Yellow", "zzzZZZ", "Swim", "Walk",         "Claw", "Hunt", "Mark Territory", 22);

    public inter() {
        topPanel = new JPanel();
        topPanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        leftPanel = new JPanel();
        leftPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        rightPanel = new JPanel();
        rightPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setBackground(Color.darkGray);
        middlePanel  = new JPanel();
        middlePanel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);
        allPanels = new JPanel();

        allPanels.setLayout(new BoxLayout(allPanels, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        topPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0));


        play = new JButton("Play");
        sleep = new JButton("Sleep");
        feed = new JButton("Feed");
        hunt = new JButton("Hunt");
        swim = new JButton("Swim");
        walk = new JButton("Roam");
        shop = new JButton("Shop");
        home = new JButton("Home");
        tigerText = new JTextArea();
        bottomPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(25,25,25, 25));
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 4, 50, 10));
        bottomPanel.add(play);
        bottomPanel.add(sleep);
        bottomPanel.add(feed);
        bottomPanel.add(hunt);
        bottomPanel.add(swim);
        bottomPanel.add(walk);
        bottomPanel.add(shop);
        bottomPanel.add(home);
        middlePanel.add(tigerText);


        leftPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());     
            ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("Images/Timmy the Tiger.jpg");
            leftPanel.add(new JLabel(image));
            leftPanel.setVisible(true);

        rightPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 30, 30));
        rightPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        tigerText = new JTextArea(); 
        tigerLabel = new JLabel(); 
        middlePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,0)); 
        middlePanel.add(tigerLabel); 
        middlePanel.add(tigerText); 

        happyBar = new JProgressBar();
        happyBar.setMinimum(0);
        happyBar.setMaximum(500);
        happyBar.repaint();
        happyLabel = new JLabel("Happy");
        happyLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        hungryBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        hungryLabel = new JLabel("Hungry");
        hungryBar.repaint();
        hungryLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        energyBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        energyLabel = new JLabel("Energy");
        energyBar.repaint();
        energyLabel.setForeground(Color.white);

        hygieneBar = new JProgressBar(0,500);
        hygieneBar.setIndeterminate(true);
        hygieneLabel = new JLabel("Hygiene");
        hygieneBar.repaint();
        hygieneLabel.setForeground(Color.white);


        rightPanel.add(happyBar);
        rightPanel.add(happyLabel);
        happyLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        happyBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        rightPanel.add(hungryBar);
        rightPanel.add(hungryLabel);
        hungryLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        hungryBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        rightPanel.add(energyBar);
        rightPanel.add(energyLabel);
        energyLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        energyBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5,5);

        rightPanel.add(hygieneBar);
        rightPanel.add(hygieneLabel);
        hygieneLabel.setBounds(5, 5, 5, 5);
        hygieneBar.setBounds(15, 5, 5, 5);

        hygieneBar.setValue(tigerHygieneCount);
        hungryBar.setValue(tigerHungerCount);
        energyBar.setValue(tigerEnergyCount);
        happyBar.setValue(tigerHappyCount);

        allPanels.add(topPanel);
        allPanels.add(leftPanel);
        allPanels.add(middlePanel);
        allPanels.add(bottomPanel);
        allPanels.add(rightPanel);


        tigerWindow = new JFrame();
        tigerWindow.setTitle("Pet Game: Tiger");
        tigerWindow.setSize(800,300);
        tigerWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        tigerWindow.setVisible(true);
        tigerWindow.add(allPanels);

        tigerWindow.getContentPane().add(leftPanel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        tigerWindow.getContentPane().add(rightPanel,BorderLayout.EAST);
        tigerWindow.getContentPane().add(bottomPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        tigerWindow.getContentPane().add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);

    }

        public JButton getPlayButton() {
            return play;
        }

        public JButton getSleepButton() {
            return sleep;
        }

        public JButton getFeedButton() {
            return feed;
        }

        public JButton getHuntButton() {
            return hunt;
        }

        public JButton getWalkButton() {
            return walk;
        }

        public JButton getSwimButton() {
            return swim;
        }

        public JButton getShopButton() {
            return shop;
        }

        public JButton getHomeButton() {
            return home;
        }

        public JPanel getPanels() {
            return allPanels;
        }

        play.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        tiger.getPlay();
        updateProgressBars();
        tigerText.append("You have played with your pet\n");
        tiger.death();
    }
        });

        sleep.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                tiger.getSleep();
                updateProgressBars();
                tigerText.append("Your dog is asleep: Z Z Z\n");
                tiger.death();
            }
        });

        feed.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                tiger.getFeed();
                updateProgressBars();
                tigerText.append("You have fed your pet\n");
                tiger.death();
            }
        });

        hunt.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                tiger.getHunt();
                updateProgressBars();
                tigerText.append("Your Tiger has gone to hunt");
                tiger.death();
            }
        });

        walk.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                tiger.getRoam();
                updateProgressBars();
                tigerText.append("Your Tiger has begun to roam");
                tiger.death();
            }
        });

        swim.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                tiger.getSwim();
                updateProgressBars();
                tigerText.append("You have washed your dog\n");
                tiger.death();
            }
        });
            }

        {
            home.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                }
            });

            shop.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){ 
                }
            });

        }

    public void updateProgressBars()
    {
        hungryBar.setValue(tiger.getHungry());
        energyBar.setValue(tiger.getEnergy());
        hygieneBar.setValue(tiger.getHygiene());
        happyBar.setValue(tiger.getHappy());
    }


    public void death()
    {
        tiger.death();
        tigerText.append("Dog has died\n");
    }



    public void play() {
        hungryBar.setValue(tigerHungerCount--);
        energyBar.setValue(tigerEnergyCount--);
        hygieneBar.setValue(tigerHygieneCount--);
        happyBar.setValue(tigerHappyCount++);
        tigerText.append("You have played with your tiger");
        tigerText.append("\n");
    }

    public void sleep() {
        hungryBar.setValue(tigerHungerCount--);
        energyBar.setValue(tigerEnergyCount ++);
        hygieneBar.setValue(tigerHygieneCount --);
        happyBar.setValue(tigerHappyCount ++);
        tigerText.append("You let your tiger sleep");
        tigerText.append("\n");
    }

    public void feed() {
        hungryBar.setValue(tigerHungerCount++);
        energyBar.setValue(tigerEnergyCount --);
        hygieneBar.setValue(tigerHygieneCount --);
        happyBar.setValue(tigerHappyCount ++);
        tigerText.append("You have fed your tiger");
        tigerText.append("\n");
    }

    public void hunt() {
        hungryBar.setValue(tigerHungerCount++);
        energyBar.setValue(tigerEnergyCount --);
        hygieneBar.setValue(tigerHygieneCount --);
        happyBar.setValue(tigerHappyCount ++);
        tigerText.append("You let your tiger hunt");
        tigerText.append("\n");
    }

    public void walk() {
        hungryBar.setValue(tigerHungerCount++);
        energyBar.setValue(tigerEnergyCount --);
        hygieneBar.setValue(tigerHygieneCount --);
        happyBar.setValue(tigerHappyCount ++);
        tigerText.append("You made your tiger roam");
        tigerText.append("\n");
    }

    public void swim() {
        hungryBar.setValue(tigerHungerCount--);
        energyBar.setValue(tigerEnergyCount --);
        hygieneBar.setValue(tigerHygieneCount ++);
        happyBar.setValue(tigerHappyCount ++);
        tigerText.append("You made your tiger go for a swim");
        tigerText.append("\n");
    }

        }
```

please help?
I have tried everything, nothing seems to make sence. it was working fine 2 days ago, next thing i know it wasn't showing up at all. I don't have a clue! I dont see a reason for it not to work. im so stuck here. please help.

Comment: Post the code for Pet here maybe then someone can copy your code and give it a try at their local systems and respond back with  findings.

Comment: You've tried everything? You haven't shown us where you set your JFrame to visible, so how can we know what might be wrong?? Have you even gone through the tutorials on this? That would be your best bet, I think.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 0):

First try with a simple `JFrame`  with an empty label as follows:

```
public class JFrameDemo {

    public static void main(String s[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("JFrame Source Demo");
        // Add a window listner for close button
        frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        // This is an empty content area in the frame
        JLabel jlbempty = new JLabel("");
        jlbempty.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(175, 100));
        frame.getContentPane().add(jlbempty, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If it is working go ahead with your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your inter class does not extend JFrame.

Try putting this when you declare your class block:

```
    public class inter extends JFrame {...
```

I think that this will help.